# glmulti and rational expressions in R

Tags: r, glm, data-fitting

#### Background

The purpose of a generalized linear model, as I understand it, is to allow one to fit coefficients of a linear model in the presence of noise that is not normally distributed.

The 'glmulti' package allows one to evaluate many candidate coefficient combinations to find the one that has highest yield in fit (minimum error) for lowest cost (number of coefficients) using information criteria like akaike information criterion (aic) or Bayes information criterion (bic).

For my case, I suspect that instead of being a purely linear expression of the variables, I may have a rational expression.

#### Question

Is there a clean way to fit this using an off-the-shelf package for R?  I know that the MatLab (or MATLAB) curve fit toolbox has a rational fit, but that requires two very large purchases. If not in R, is there an option using another language like python, [sage](http://nb.sagemath.org/), or similar?

Comment: math notation doesn't work on SO, only on CV

Comment: that part is truncated.